# splitting of the Hodge filtration

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, hodge-theory

Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety over a subfield $k$ of $\mathbb{C}$. Then one has a short exact sequence

$$
0 \to H^0(X, \Omega^1_X) \to H^1_{dR}(X/k) \to H^1(X, \mathcal{O}_X) \to 0 
$$

One knows that, after tensoring by $\mathbb{C}$, this sequence becomes split, as $H^1_{dR}(X/k) \otimes_k \mathbb{C}$ is canonically isomorphic to the singular cohomology $H^1(X(\mathbb{C}), \mathbb{C})$ which carries a Hodge structure.

**Question**: Are there criteria for this sequence to be already split over $k$?

Already the case of curves seems pretty interesting.

Comment: Any short exact sequence of vector spaces splits.

Comment: Do you want to consider a flat family of varieties?

Comment: not an expert, but isn't that just the degeneration of the Hodge-dR spectral sequence ?

Comment: I think the OP means: "When is the canonical Hodge splitting already defined over $k$ ?". This happens rarely and the failure to split over $k$ is basically encoded in the Mumford-Tate group, about which there are many deep conjectures. For instance if $X$ is a CM abelian variety and $k$ contains the Galois closure of the CM field, then the sequence splits (and the Mumford-Tate group is a torus).